# How to Hide/Show button in Index page of Angular 6 app?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

I am new to `Angular 6`. I am working on a backend admin panel that requires the users to login first to get access to the application features.

Everything is working fine, but I am stuck in one thing. I have put my

> Logout

button on the index page of the Angular 6 app.

Problem is the `Logout button` also be shown on the `login page`. I need to hide that button.

Index.html

```
...
<body>
<div class="logo-top">
<img src="/app/Content/Images/logo.png" class="logo">
<button *ngIf="nav.isShowLogoutButton" id="logoutButton" type="button" class="btn  btn-default btn-sm float-md-right center-block" style=" margin-right: 40px;margin-top: 20px;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out
</button>
```

I have made NavbarService hide/show navigation bar in login and other pages. But I can't use `*ngIf="nav.isShowLogoutButton` as I think there is no component for the index page.

Is there any way to hide/show HTML elements in index page depending upon your choice in each subsequent components?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that `*ngIf` isn't going to work because it's placed outside of the Angular bootstrap process.

> You should put dynamic items inside Angular

To avoid entering of users on some routes of your application and force them to login you should use [route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards).

And if you don't want to load your entyre application just to login (because it could be a heavy app) you should consider using [Asynchronous Loading](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-6-asynchronous-routing). That is use [guards to lazy load](https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules) only the modules your users is authorized to see.

There could be multiple solutions to what you are looking for. But the approach I'm suggesting would be easier to maintain and debug.

---

But if you still want to do it your way, you can be dirty and change the DOM directly from Angular using `document.getElementsByClassName()` or `element.getElementsByTagName()` and change its attributes, you can select from `style.display = 'none'` to `setAttribute('hidden', 'true')`. You have options.

It have set a [working StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kp3mix).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I am using Route guards. that's not what I am asking here. I am just having issue how can I hide an html element in the index.html of angular 6 app if I am at any authorized page. there is no component there in index.html of an application

Comment: I have updated the answer. *Beware* the consequences, for it might bite you on the afterlife. But anyways, have fun with it.

Comment: You're welcome. Just remember, the best way to show someone that you are thankful to them is to accept their answer. Also, that way others can find the right answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the best way to handle this kind of behavior is for the application to have a shared `AuthenticationService` which keeps the user login state, and inject this service into all components and guards that need it.

Services are singletons in Angular, so all components will get the same instance.

See http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/16/angular-6-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial for an example, this also contains guards to prevent access to authenticated routes when unauthenticated.

Comment: Thank you for your response, can you please read the comment in above answer please?